# A Way to Avoid Figures being Numbered in Minipage

Tags: floats, minipage, sidewaysfigure

I am currently putting together a sideways figure, which will eventually include 16 different pictures. To do this I use the minipage command/environment.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[p]
        \centering
    \begin{minipage}[$\mathnormal{t\textsubscript{p}}$]{0.12\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_1.jpeg}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{Probe 1, vorher}
        \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_1}
    \end{minipage}
    %\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[$\mathnormal{t\textsubscript{p}}$]{0.12\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_2.jpeg}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{Probe 2, vorher}
        \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_2}
    \end{minipage}
    %\hfill

% and so on... sixteen times

\caption{Fotografien der standardisierte bzw. geometriekonstante Klebstoffprobenkörper der Messreihe 1 vor und nach der Untersuchung im DSC-Messgerät}}
\label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Currently all images for each minipage are being counted as a separate figure. This is just fine in some cases. However in this case I would only like the entire figure, iniciated by \begin{sidewaysfigure}, to count into the figure count, while avoiding every figure, iniciated by \begin{minipage} to count in. Is there a (simple) way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards
Timon

Comment: use \subcaption instead of \caption inside the minipages, see the subcaption package.

Comment: Or caption* for entirely unnumbered captions.

Comment: @Timon - If my answer has been useful to you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions and observations, in no particular order:

- Be sure to load the `subcaption` package and replace all instances of `{minipage}` within the `sidewaysfigure` environment with `{subfigure}`. (Basically, a `subfigure` environment *is* a `minipage` -- with the added bonus of knowing what to do if it encounters a `\caption` statement.)
- I have no idea what `[$\mathnormal{t\textsubscript{p}}$]{0.12\linewidth}` is supposed to achieve -- except, maybe, to create needless clutter while making sure that it'll get ignored. Use `[t]` instead.
- No need to have `\captionsetup` instructions inside each and every `subfigure` environment. A single

  ```
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  ```

  instruction immediately after `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` suffices.
- `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable` environments are *always* placed on a page by themselves. The `[p]` placement specifier is therefore ignored -- and should be omitted.
- None of the `\centering` instructions do anything. Drop them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.225\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_1.jpeg}
    \caption{Probe 1, vorher}
    \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.225\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_2.jpeg}
    \caption{Probe 2, vorher}
    \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.225\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_3.jpeg}
    \caption{Probe 3, vorher}
    \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.225\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Images/Ergebnisse/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher/Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_4.jpeg}
    \caption{Probe 4, vorher}
    \label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher_4}
    \end{subfigure}

% and so on... twelve more times

\caption{Fotografien der standardisierten bzw. geometriekonstanten Klebstoffprobenkörper der Messreihe 1 vor und nach der Untersuchung im DSC-Messgerät}
\label{Klebstoffprobenkoerper_Messreihe_1_vorher}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the answer of @Mico even more complete: Using `\subcaption{text}` and `\caption*{text}`, as was proposed in the comment section, both worked with `\begin{minipage}` as well.

Thank you all!